# C++: Dynamic programming, given 3 possible operations

Tags: c++, dynamic

Question:
So the question goes like this: I have N numbers. For each number X in the array of length N, I can perform 3 operations: 1. If X is a multiple of 2, divide X by 2. 2. If X is a multiple of 3, divide it by 3. 3. Subtract 1 from X. Find the minimum number of operations to make X = 0. This code is meant to be done using dynamic programming...

Input:
line 1: N line 2: Array X of N numbers

Output:
line 1: Number of operations to reduce X1 to 0. ... line N: Number of operations to reduce XN to 0.

So how should I go about doing this?

Code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        int A, count = 0;
        cin >> A;
        while (A > 0){
            if (A%2 == 0){
                A /= 2;
                count++;
            }
            else if (A%3 == 0){
                A /= 3;
                count++;
            }
            else{
                A--;
                count++;
            }
        }
    cout << count << "\n";
  }
}
```

This code which I currently have in mind does not work for some cases(meaning I do not output the desired solution, and that the code is a working code), say Xi = 10. My code does 10/2, then -1, then /2, then /2 then -1, so it is 5 operations. However, the optimal is 10 -1, /3, /3 again, then -1, which is 4 operations. Anyone has any idea how I should code my solution to this problem? Thanks! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't think it matters, and if you are not keen to help, then please do not say such things

Comment: If that's the  case, then what kinds of question should I ask?

Comment: Firstly, this question is NOT an interview question NOR a question from a meaning less site. It is a problem my tutor posed. I am sorry if I have to bold the words to let you see them much more clearly. Along the same lines, one would find YOUR posts meaningless too!  Lastly, I feel that such unhelpful comments are not needed.  Simply answering my query would be sufficient.

Comment: I would hence like to know why I was downvoted

Comment: Huh I didnt delete my question, I edited so I could get the badge :p.  Anyways it is indeed a tutor posed question and I believe that it does not matter, all question should receive some sort of attention, and I believe that a true programmer does not reject a question due to its source.  I you think so highly of yourself, I think that there is no need for you to state these comments.  @Jarod42 has already kindly answered my query in one post, and I believe that you are merely trying no show off and look down on me.

Comment: After reading what questions are acceptable to ask here, I have my queries confirmed.  All questions are allowed as Long as it is stated clearly.  Here, I have given my code that I have, and the desired output.  If you are misinformed about this, perhaps you could visit the help page.  Lastly, you can go to stackexchange and see my post.  I was instructed by a moderator to come here to pose my query.  I hope you can stop insisting the meaninglessness of my query, and I am willing to accept my consequences of downvote(not being able to ask qns), in hope that I can resolve this in a civil manner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said dynamic programming:

```
std::vector<int> v{0};

for (int i = 1; i != N + 1; ++i) {
    v.push_back(v.back() + 1);
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        v.back() = std::min(v.back(), v[i / 2] + 1);
    }
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        v.back() = std::min(v.back(), v[i / 3] + 1);
    }
}
return v.back();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!   :)